# find the sum on json list based on condition in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Nested Json sample:

```
{
    "accounts": {
        "1": [{
            "userId": "XXXXXXX",
            "accountId": "1",
            "externalId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
            "status": "x",
            "planId": "1",
            "investmentObjective": null,
            "vestedBalance": 50097.01,
            "payoutAction": "0",
            "payoutAmount": 0.0,
            "bacs": "xxx-xxxx-xxxx",
            "rkId": "xxx",
            "planOwnerId": "xxxx",
            "userExternalId": "xxxxxxx"
        }],
        "2": [{ 
            "userId": "XXXXXXX",
            "accountId": "2",
            "externalId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
            "status": "X",
            "planId": "1",
            "investmentObjective": "I",
            "vestedBalance": 00.0,
            "payoutAction": "0",
            "payoutAmount": 50097.01,
            "bacs": "xxx-xxxx-xxxx",
            "rkId": "xxx",
            "planOwnerId": "xxxxxx",
            "userExternalId": "xxxxxxx"
        
        }],
        "3": [{ 
            "userId": "XXXXXXX",
            "accountId": "3",
            "externalId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
            "status": "X",
            "planId": "1",
            "investmentObjective": "I",
            "vestedBalance": 00.0,
            "payoutAction": "0",
            "payoutAmount": 2100.00,
            "bacs": "xxx-xxxx-xxxx",
            "rkId": "xxx",
            "planOwnerId": "xxxxxx",
            "userExternalId": "xxxxxxx"
        
        }]
    }
}
```

I need to calculate the “sumpayoutamount” on the below condition

“sumpayoutamount”: SUM(payoutAmount) of accounts with investmentObjective = "I"

Above example : “sumpayoutamount”: 50097.01 + 2100.00 for investmentObjective = "I"

How do i achieve this in Pyspark? Thanks

Comment: I couldn't find any list here.

Comment: Sample records for accounts with list

Comment: +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+----+----+  
|1                                                                                            |10  |11  |12  |13  |14  |15  |2  |22  |3   |  
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+--------------- 
|[1, xxxxxx:xxxxxxxxx, xxxxxx,, 0, 0.0, 1, xxxxx, xxxx, y, xxxx-xxx-xxx, 23180107, 1299381.41]|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|